# Change in F vs x graph if spring is torn in half?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

The force required to stretch a spring varies with the distance as shown in the figure. If the experiment is performed with the above spring of half the length, the line OA will:
[image]

(a) shift toward F-axis

(b) shift towards X-axis

(c) remain as it is

(d) become double in length

If we cut the spring into half the length, the new force constant $K_{new}=2K_{org}$.

Since force is proportional to force constant(the new one). So the force must have doubled. So the line OA should shift to F. But the answer in the book is given to be (b). Can anyone explain this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a value of F that stretches the spring, that force is present in all parts of the spring. If the end of the spring has moved 2cm, how far has the mid point of the spring moved?

Comment: the mid point of the spring would move 2cm as well. What are you trying to imply?